# export data to excel fetched from database

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to export data fetched from DB to an excel sheet, when user clicks on `excel` icon on the screen in the following way. It actually works fine but just wanted to get a better idea on this rather than reading the buffered data.

```
private void exportLayout(String date,
         PrintWriter prn,
         BufferedReader in ) throws Exception
    {
        String line = null; // Indicates current line
        boolean isNotEndofBuffer = true; // boolean to indicate if the end of buffer is reached
        boolean skip = false; // boolean to indicate if we can skip reading the current line

        try
        {
            while (isNotEndofBuffer)
            {
                if (!skip)
                {
                    line =  in.readLine();                  
                }
                if (line != null)
                {
                     ...

                     ExportUtil.outputLine(prn, TEXT1 +
                TEXT2 + TAB +
             TEXT3 + TAB );


catch( IOException ioe )
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            throw ioe;
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;

        }
```

Comment: The database output evidently is written as lines (BufferedReader) and then reconverted to fields and written to a tab-separated text file, suitable for Excel. A bit over-engineered.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need any code, By using this query you can export database table to excel

Export data from MySQL into a CSV file,Its simple by using this query.

```
   SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/name.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   ESCAPED BY '\\'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   FROM [tablename]
```